# Where are templates to django-filter package?

Tags: django-crispy-forms, django-filter

I am a little bit confused.

https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/develop/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py

From line 31 to 37 - here is a logic, if I have crispy instaled, package should use django_filters/rest_framework/crispy_form.html file.

I have installed all newest packages of django-filter and crispy forms, but all the time I have an error in my code:

Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:

django_filters/rest_framework/crispy_form.html

Could you please explain me where I can find all needed templates? Which repo? I don't see these files in django-filter repo, so I am little bit lost.

Answer (score 44):

You may need to add 'django_filters' to INSTALLED_APPS. I had same issue resolved by doing this.

Answer (score 2):

> I have installed all newest packages of django-filter and crispy forms...

Please check this.

The backend [catches the missing template exception](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/develop/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py#L84-L87) so you shouldn't see that error.

The reason you can't see the template file is that [the default templates are defined in the module](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/develop/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py#L12-L28), to avoid the extra files and the need to add Django Filter to `INSTALLED_APPS`. You can override these by adding files at the expected path(s).

The behaviour you're seeing is unexpected so if you can reduce it to a minimal reproducible example please [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/new).

Please [look at the test case here](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/develop/tests/rest_framework/test_backends.py#L324-L347) — this covers the exact behaviour:

> Ensure backend renders default if template path does not exist

The question is, why is that not working in your case?

Comment: I solved the problem by adding my own backend class. from rest_framework_filters import backends class CustomBackend(backends.DjangoFilterBackend): template = 'rest_framework/filters/django_filter.html'